# Reflectivity of metallic surfaces

Tags: optics, material-science, reflection, optical-materials

Can someone please point me to an academically verified web resource/page that tabulates the Reflectivity of various metallic surfaces like gold, silver , aluminum, etc.? I have found a [list on Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/light-material-reflecting-factor-d_1842.html) but I am not sure of its credibility. I would prefer an academic resource to cite in my work.

Thank You

Rohan

Comment: Reflectivity depends very much on surface conditioning and there are no easy answers here. Try reading http://www.photonics.com/EDU/Handbook.aspx?AID=25501 for starters, it will give you a little more detail what's going on for technical purposes. The detailed theory is a lot deeper, still...

Comment: Thanks for the link..yes I understand that it is both a function of surface roughness and the material property

Answer (score 1):

From [refractiveindex.info](http://refractiveindex.info/) you can get *n* and *k* for many different materials, as a function of wavelength, and the site even includes a calculator at the bottom with which you can calculate the reflectivity *R*.

All of the provided data are backed up with citations.

Comment: This is not so much a physics answer as a link to a black box.

Comment: @BenCrowell The site lists n&k values for many materials over broad ranges of wavelength with scientific reference. Definitely not a black box and precisely the answer requested.